# Google places not working with Ionic 4 on device

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, google-places-api

I tried using `**Google Places API** in my`**ionic 4**`app to show nearby hospitals. It works when I run it on a browser, I get the results. But it does not work when I test it from my`android` phone.

I read somewhere that `Google` doesn't let you use the places rest api directly from within an app(because of `CORS` issue), it has to be called by a backend server. Is that true? Is there any way I can use the places api from my app.
Link : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-google-places-api-not-working-on-debug-android-app/180301

Here's my code :

index.html

```
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

providers: [
    Geolocation,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ]
```

component.ts

```
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions ,Geoposition ,PositionError } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx'; 

declare var google;

ionViewDidEnter() { this.getUserPosition(); }

getUserPosition(){
    this.options = { enableHighAccuracy : true};
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then((pos : Geoposition) => {
        this.currentPos = pos;      
        var request = {
          location: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude),
          radius: '4000',
          types: ['hospital']
      };
      var container = document.getElementById('results');
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(container);
      service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            results.forEach(ele => {
              var hospObj = {};
              hospObj['name'] = ele.name;
              hospObj['vicinity'] = ele.vicinity;
              this.places.push(hospObj);
            });
        }
      });
    },(err : PositionError)=>{
      this.err = err.message;
        console.log("error : " + err.message);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by " it does not work"? This is not an error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you're likely using web-based authentication (locked to IP or host-name), while you'd need Android app authentication (locked to the package-name and the signature fingerprint). To make this work without using a web-server, you'd need a simple Cordova plugin, which performs these calls (and acts as kind of local "server" for your JavaScript application). See the [Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro).

Using an unrestricted key is not suggested, that's alike forgetting your credit card somewhere.

> Before you can start using the Google Maps Platform APIs and SDKs, you must sign up and create a billing account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually There's to type of Google Maps that you can use with ionic 
But the Geolocation from native ionic needs an android key from google cloud platfrom in config.xml file

```
<widget ...>
  <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
  <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
</widget>
```